# Failing to Hide and unHide jPanel in Java Netbeans after clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, splash-screen

I have a Java program, and I would like when I press the Start button, a certain jPanel which I have set the visibility to false, to be made true, and then the other false. Then after loading for it to open another window (Main.java).

[Home.java]

```
public Home() {
    initComponents();
    loadGamePanel.setVisible(false);
}
```

then after clicking the button:

```
private void startGameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jPanel1.setVisible(false);
    loadGamePanel.setVisible(true);
    if(kid.isSelected()){
        Difficulty ="Kid";
    }else if(disciple.isSelected()){
        Difficulty ="Disciple";
    }else if(giant.isSelected()){
        Difficulty ="Giant";
    }
    
    try {
        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++){
        Thread.sleep(50);
        loadGameText.setText(Integer.toString(i)+"%");
        if(i==100){
          Main main = new Main();  
          new Home().setVisible(false);
          dispose();
          main.setVisible(true);
        }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {            
    }
}
```

But this is not working, it just opens the other window without showing the 'loadGamePanel'. Please Help.

Comment: *a certain jPanel which I have set the visibility to false, to be made true, and then the other false* - use a `CardLayout`. It allows you to swap panels in the same area of the frame. It will manage the visibility of each panel for you. See: [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: @camickr This seems more like an answer than a comment. Can you post it as such so it can receive proper recognition?